# mod_rewrite breaks http basic auth

Tags: mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

After successfully getting a rewrite working as I wished for with GIT I managed to break authentication which is required to push to git.

For some reason it seems like the rewrite to the `ScriptAlias` drops the authentication info if requesting with `http://username:password@domain.tld/` which makes it impossible to push data.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/subgit/repos

    <Directory /home/subgit/repos>
        Options       None
        AllowOverride none
        Order         allow,deny
        Allow         from all
    </Directory>

CustomLog /home/subgit/logs/access_log combined
SuexecUserGroup subgit subgit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^git
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /git/testrepo/$1 [PT]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]

ScriptAlias /git/ /home/subgit/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/

 <LocationMatch "/git/">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from env=AUTHREQUIRED
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "subgit"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /home/subgit/etc/subgit
    Require valid-user
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [PT] also entails [L] any rule below it wasn't executed, moving the AUTHREQUIRED rule above solved the issue.